# Selecting from multiple tables with Yii's CActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii

I have 3 tables: `Topics`, `Users` and `Details` (those are some of the tables of a custom forum)

`Topics` contains (among other usual fields) the id (FK) of the user that created the topic.
`Users` contains nick/pass and id (PK)
`Details` contains (among other usual fields) the id (FK) of the user.

Relations:
One user can have one 1 detail.
One user can have multiple topics, but a topic can be created only by one user.

Topic relations:

```
return array(
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'User_iduser'),
);
```

User relations:

```
return array(
    'details' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Details', 'User_iduser'),
);
```

I'm trying to get a list with Topics and User details (let's say for example the topic name and the user's name).

Currently I have this:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Topic', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
    'with'=>array('user.details')
    )
));
```

But as you can imagine, it's not working (read as in it's not selecting anything from the tbles Users or Details).

What's wrong with my code?

+++++++++++++++

This code selects fields from the table user (and the topic table):

```
Topic::model()->with('user')->findAll();
```

But this one won't select from details, users and topic:

```
Topic::model()->with('user.details')->findAll();
```

Also, I need a `CActiveDataProvider` solution as I need it for zii widgets (means, even if some kind of modification on the `Topic::model()->with()....` code get's to select from the 3 tables it won't be really helpful)

EDIT: (SQL log from Yii)

```
Querying SQL: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`idtema`) FROM `tema` `t`  LEFT
OUTER JOIN `usuario` `usuarioIdusuario` ON
(`t`.`Usuario_idusuario`=`usuarioIdusuario`.`idusuario`)  LEFT OUTER JOIN
`detallesusuario` `detallesusuario` ON
(`detallesusuario`.`Usuario_idusuario`=`usuarioIdusuario`.`idusuario`) 

Querying SQL: SELECT `t`.`idtema` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`Usuario_idusuario` AS
`t0_c1`, `t`.`Categoria_idcategoria` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`tema` AS `t0_c3`,
`t`.`fecha_hora` AS `t0_c4`, `usuarioIdusuario`.`idusuario` AS `t1_c0`,
`usuarioIdusuario`.`nick` AS `t1_c1`, `usuarioIdusuario`.`contrasena` AS
`t1_c2`, `usuarioIdusuario`.`email` AS `t1_c3`,
`detallesusuario`.`Usuario_idusuario` AS `t2_c0`,
`detallesusuario`.`nombre` AS `t2_c1`, `detallesusuario`.`apellidos` AS
`t2_c2`, `detallesusuario`.`cumpleanos` AS `t2_c3`,
`detallesusuario`.`telefono1` AS `t2_c4`, `detallesusuario`.`telefono2` AS
`t2_c5` FROM `tema` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `usuario` `usuarioIdusuario` ON
(`t`.`Usuario_idusuario`=`usuarioIdusuario`.`idusuario`)  LEFT OUTER JOIN
`detallesusuario` `detallesusuario` ON
(`detallesusuario`.`Usuario_idusuario`=`usuarioIdusuario`.`idusuario`) 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: HI, How did u solved this problem. I'm facing same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Topic', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
    'with'=>array('user'=>array('alias'=>'user','with'=>array('details'=>array('alias'=>'details'))))
    )
));
```

And

```
Topic::model()->with(array('user'=>array('alias'=>'user','with'=>array('details'=>array('alias'=>'details')))))->findAll();
```

Comment: Well, that code as-it-is won't do anything more than mine, but adding ```$dataProvider->getData();``` and then ```var_dump($dataProvider)``` will show me fileds from the users table. So I'm missing the details table. Weird thing about this is that Yii isn't complaining about anything (read as no-errors-shown-anywhere), but it just doesn't show what I want.

Comment: @alexandernst add `CWebLogRoute` or `CProfileLogRoute` in your application config. Its already there you only need to uncomment it

Comment: whats the problem then? Its already selecting from both `details` and `users` tables as seen in the first sql

Comment: The problem is that I can't access any field from the details table. I mean, if I go to the _view.php and write a var_dump($data), I see the fields from the topics and the users tables, but not the details table. Maybe accessing variables from third table is done in a different way?

Comment: what is output of `var_dump($data->user)` and `var_dump($data->user->details)`in the _view.php file?

Comment: var_dumo($data->user) returns the fields that I want + some Yii stuff. $data->user->details is NULL. (also, running the SQL query agains my database is returning the right data, so, the data is there, it's just that Yii is refusing get it)

Comment: @alexandernst waht about athe non activedataprovider solution i posted as an edit to the answer?

Comment: It's not working either. I can see the fileds from Topics and Users using a var_dump, but I can't see anything from Details.

Comment: then i suspect there is something wrong with the relation you specified in the user model. May be a spelling error or something

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16505/discussion-between-alexandernst-and-dingd0ng)

Answer (score 2):

instead of the line

```
'with'=>array('user.details')
```

use

```
'with'=>array('user')
```

then add

```
$criteria->compare( 'user.details', $query, true );
$criteria->together = true;
}
```

*Where $query is a variable that will be searched in column details